# Can people access the Android realm file easily?

Tags: java, android, realm

Can people hack the realm file to get the data in Android apps? I need to have a persistent object to save data to, so users can load it back when they restart.

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    /* May need to take out the folioing line. */
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration); 
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the the `RealmConfiguration` is built through [`Builder(android.content.Context context)`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#Builder-android.content.Context-) , the Realm file will be stored in `/data/data/<packagename>/files`. It is in the Android internal storage, and by default, only your app has the permission to access. See [Saving files - Android doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). For a developer, there are some ways to get the file from the internal storage even he is not the owner of your app (eg.: root the phone :P).

You can choose to use Realm's encryption feature, which means even if others get the Realm file, it is still not possible to decode the data from the file. See [`Realm Encryption`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#encryption) for more details.